# Работа с вложенными словарями Python

Tags: python, dict

Имеется словарь :

```
    x = {
        "count": 6, "items": [{"id": 18, "from_id": 48585484}]
    }
```

Как мне отсюда вытащить все значения с ключом id? Проблема в том, что там еще список и нельзя просто написав `x["items"]["id"]` вывести нужное мне значение.

Comment: x["items"][0]["id"]

Comment: Я разобрался `wall_id1=wall_id["items"]

print(wall_id1[1]["id"])`

Comment: Это не совсем вложенные словари, здесь в значении словаря лежит список, а в списке лежит элемент словарь